# How to fix my R code on retrieving XML data and turning into a data frame?

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

I am aiming to write a proper R code that would retrieved the xml data from this link: https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/observations/V39079/xml. The xml data looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVu6C.png)

My code so far is:

```
library(XML)
# u is the link to the desired xml data
u <- "https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/observations/V39079/xml"
# f is path to the xml file with data downloaded from the above link
f <- "C:/Users/19132/Downloads/V39079.xml"
d <- XML::xmlParse(f) 
df <- data.frame(as.list(unlist(xmlToList(d, addAttributes = TRUE, simplify = TRUE))))
```

The result of this code is a data frame with one row and 9138 columns and looks like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJt2p.png)

What I need is to get a 'vertical' data frame with three columns:

```
Indicator  Date        Value
V39079     2009-04-26  0.25
V39079     2009-04-27  0.25
...
```

I will appreciate very much your helpful suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Making use of `xml2` and `dplyr` this could be achieved like so:

```r
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

u <- "https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/observations/V39079/xml"

f <- xml2::read_xml(u)

doc <- xml2::as_list(f)

d <- lapply(doc$data$observations, function(x) data.frame(Value = x$v[[1]], Indicator = attr(x$v, "s"), Date = attr(x, "d")))
d <- dplyr::bind_rows(d)

head(d)
#>   Value Indicator       Date
#> 1  0.25    V39079 2009-04-21
#> 2  0.25    V39079 2009-04-22
#> 3  0.25    V39079 2009-04-23
#> 4  0.25    V39079 2009-04-24
#> 5  0.25    V39079 2009-04-27
#> 6  0.25    V39079 2009-04-28
```

Comment: could you please comment on my reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65413943/14866982

Comment: @Alex Do `d <- lapply(doc$MKR, ...)`. This will loop over all the records.

Comment: Thanks very much! Works nicely.

Comment: Could you please take a quick look at my next question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/65424748/14866982

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use just the `XML` package and I used `dplyr` just to reorder the cols.

```
library(XML)
# u is the link to the desired xml data
u <- "https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/observations/V39079/xml"
# f is path to the xml file with data downloaded from the above link
f <- "C:/Users/19132/Downloads/V39079.xml"
d <- XML::xmlParse(f) 

xml_list <-xmlToList(d)
df <- data.frame()
for( i in 1:length(xml_list$observations)){
temp <- data.frame(xml_list$observations[[i]])
rownames(temp)<- c()
df <- rbind(df, temp)
}

# rename cols
names(df) <- c("Value", "Indicator", "Date")

# reorder cols
library(dplyr)
df <- select(df, Indicator, Date, Value)

# See if it worked 
head(df)


Indicator       Date Value
1    V39079 2009-04-21  0.25
2    V39079 2009-04-22  0.25
3    V39079 2009-04-23  0.25
4    V39079 2009-04-24  0.25
5    V39079 2009-04-27  0.25
6    V39079 2009-04-28  0.25
```

Comment: I does work very well on my side. I appreciate your insight very much!