# R and XML: 'Subscript out of bound' error

Tags: r, xml

What I am doing wrong here? My R code:

```
u <- "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/xml_depo.asp?date_req1=01/07/2001&date_req2=22/12/2020" 
f <- xml2::read_xml(u)
doc <- xml2::as_list(f)
d <- lapply(doc$Deposit, 
        function(x) data.frame(Overnight = x$Overnight[[1]],
                               Tom_next = x$`Tom-next`[[1]],
                               Spot_next = x$`Spot-next`[[1]],
                               Spot_week = x$`Spot-week`[[1]],
                               P2weeks = x$P2weeks[[1]],
                               Spot_2week = x$`Spot-2week`[[1]],
                               P1month = x$P1month[[1]],
                               P3month = x$P3month[[1]],
                               Date = attr(x, "Date")))
d <- dplyr::bind_rows(d)
```

It breaks at the line of `d <- lapply(doc$Deposit,...` by saying that `Error in x$Overnight[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change `d <- lapply(doc$Deposit,...` to become `d <- lapply(doc$Deposit$Record,...`

Please try

```
d <- lapply(doc$Deposit$Record, 
        function(x) data.frame(Overnight = x$Overnight[[1]],
                               Tom_next = x$`Tom-next`[[1]],
                               Spot_next = x$`Spot-next`[[1]],
                               Spot_week = x$`Spot-week`[[1]],
                               P2weeks = x$P2weeks[[1]],
                               Spot_2week = x$`Spot-2week`[[1]],
                               P1month = x$P1month[[1]],
                               P3month = x$P3month[[1]],
                               Date = attr(x, "Date")))
d <- dplyr::bind_rows(d)
```

EDIT:

I am sorry, I hastily suggested that without further check.
I would suggest this :

```
d <- lapply(doc$Deposit$Record, cbind)
d <- as.data.frame(t(unlist(d)))
d
# Overnight Tom-next Spot-next P1week Spot-week P2weeks Spot-2weeks P1month P3month
# 1         2      2,3       2,5      7       7,5     8,5           9      10      12
```

Comment: Thanks! I did change it this way `d <- lapply(doc$Deposit$Record, ...` but it just produced `d` that has zero records. The result is: `> summary(d)
            Length Class      Mode
Overnight   0      data.frame list ...`

Comment: I am so sorry I was too hasty. I edited my answer. Hopefully it works.

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider accepting my answer.